# Why geom_rect colours only first row of facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to get shaded rectangles on every even-numbered panel of my `facet_wrap` plot. However, when I use `geom_rect`, it produces the rectangles only on the second panel. I tried using `annotate` and `geom_tile` but with no success. I presume I am missing some simple detail here, probably related to the fact that my X variable is categorical and not numeric, but I am fighting this for a few hours already...

Here is my code:

```
even_numbers <- seq(2,nrow(df.plt),2)
ggplot(df.plt) + 
  geom_rect(data = df.plt[even_numbers, ],
            xmin = even_numbers - 0.5, xmax = even_numbers + 0.5,
            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3, fill = 'grey') +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Cnd, y = nst, fill = Srs), position = position_dodge(0.9), outlier.shape = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Grp), ncol=1)
```

And the resulting plot:
[resulting plot with geom_rect and facet_wrap not working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TriWx.png)

Edit:

I have created a dummy dataset example which replicates my issue:

```
set.seed(002) # just to make it reproducible
df.tmp = data.frame(nst = rnorm(100*2), Srs = sample(rep(c("S3","S4"),100)), Cnd = sample(rep(c("DN","DA","DV","DAV"),50)), Grp = sample(rep(c("close","far"),100)))

even_numbers <- seq(2,nrow(df.tmp),2)
ggplot(df.tmp) + 
  geom_rect(data = df.tmp[even_numbers, ],
            xmin = even_numbers - 0.5, xmax = even_numbers + 0.5,
            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3, fill = 'grey') +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Cnd, y = nst, fill = Srs), position = position_dodge(0.9), outlier.shape = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Grp), ncol=1)
```

Comment: Are you sure `df.plt[even_numbers, ]` selects rows of `df.plt` that that will contribute to the top panel?  Without seeing your data, we can't be sure...

Comment: @Limey My apologies, I have just edited my question and added a dummy dataset example which replicates my issue (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your idea was right IMHO you could achieve your desired result more easily by putting the `xmin` and `xmax` values in a dataframe and by mapping on aesthetics. First note that we only need a vector of even numbers of `length(unique(df.tmp$Cnd))`, i.e. the number of categories of `Cnd`. Second, as we are mixing discrete and continuous x variables I added an `scale_x_discrete` before `geom_rect` as otherwise we will get an error.

```r
library(ggplot2)

even_numbers <- seq(2, length(unique(df.tmp$Cnd)), 2)

rects <- data.frame(
  xmin = even_numbers - 0.5,
  xmax = even_numbers + 0.5
)

ggplot(df.tmp) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_rect(
    data = rects, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax),
    ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3, fill = "grey"
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Cnd, y = nst, fill = Srs), position = position_dodge(0.9), outlier.shape = 1) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Grp), ncol = 1)
```

[image]

**EDIT** Just in case. The reason why your approach did not work is that the relevant part of the data used for the rects contains only the `far` group. The issue is that basically only rects corresponding to even numbers in the range 1 to 4 (the number of `Cnd` categories) are displayed. As can be seen from the following code snippet which replicates the data which under the hood is used for the rects in your approach only the `far` grp is present (after filtering for even numbers in the range 1 to 4):

```r
even_numbers <- seq(2,nrow(df.tmp),2)

dplyr::bind_cols(df.tmp[even_numbers, ], data.frame(even_number = even_numbers)) |> 
  dplyr::filter(even_number <= 4)
#>          nst Srs Cnd Grp even_number
#> 1  0.1848492  S3  DV far           2
#> 2 -1.1303757  S3  DA far           4
```

Comment: I have been thinking about this approach; I was hoping on finding one without adding new column to dataframe. Still, this solution seems easy and straightforward.
I have been trying to understand why only the second panel gets colored; I was checking my dataframe multiple times if the `df.plt[even_numbers, ]` contains only `close` or only `far` datapoints - it contains both. I created another example eventually, and I was able to get the `geom_rect` to color both segments; still, my solution seems too much of a workaround to me. I will post it though, maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: @BartłomiejMróz Just in case: I just made an edit to try to explain why your first approach fails. While you are right that both groups are present in `df.plt[even_numbers, ]`, actually only the first two rows are used for the rects or at least will show up in the plot.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. However, now I am even more confused why only first two rows are being used...

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to understand why only the second segment gets shaded. Eventually I prepared a second example, in which I have found another possible solution. However, I am not fully satisfied as I did not understand the issue with `geom_rect` / `facet_wrap`; I only found some workaround.

Here's the example:

```
# constructing the dataframe so all the combinations are present for both even and odd rows
df.tmp = data.frame(nst = rnorm(16*6), 
                    Srs = rep(c("S3", "S4"), each=8, 6), 
                    Cnd = rep(c("DN", "DA", "DV", "DAV"), each=2, 12), 
                    Grp = rep(c(rep(c("close","far"), 8), rev(rep(c("close","far"), 8))),3) )

even_numbers <- seq(2,nrow(df.tmp),2) # so the df.tmp[even_numbers, ] contains all the combinations
ggplot(df.tmp) + 
  geom_rect(data = df.tmp[even_numbers, ],
            xmin = even_numbers - 0.5, xmax = even_numbers + 0.5,
            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3, fill = 'grey') +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Cnd, y = nst, fill = Srs), position = position_dodge(0.9), outlier.shape = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Grp), ncol=1)
```

As you can see here, the plot has shaded rectangles only in the second row, despite ensuring the `df.tmp[even_numbers, ]` includes `close` datapoints as well: [image: non-shaded segments in first line]

Here I change the `ggplot` so it contains `geom_rect` separately for `close` and `far` segments:

```
even_numbers <- seq(2,length(unique(df.tmp$Cnd)),2) # here the df.tmp[even_numbers, ] doesn't need to have all the combinations
ggplot(df.tmp) + 
  geom_rect(data = df.tmp[df.tmp$Grp=="close", ][even_numbers, ],
            xmin = even_numbers - 0.5, xmax = even_numbers + 0.5,
            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3, fill = 'grey') + 
  geom_rect(data = df.tmp[df.tmp$Grp=="far", ][even_numbers, ],
            xmin = even_numbers - 0.5, xmax = even_numbers + 0.5,
            ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3, fill = 'grey') +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Cnd, y = nst, fill = Srs), position = position_dodge(0.9), outlier.shape = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Grp), ncol=1)
```

As you can see below, it works now: [image]

As I mentioned earlier, I am still not sure why `geom_rect` did not work in the first place. In my solution, a separate `geom_rect` needs to be prepared for each segment, so it's definitely not a solution for a plot with many of them. I was trying to find a more elegant way, so one wouldn't have to bother how many segments or other groupings are declared.